# Remove duplicate element from linklist

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am implementing a linked list using the code below. It will print 25 26 25 25 28 null. The problem is that im trying to remove the duplicate of 25, so i want the final output to be 25 26 28 null. Is it possible to do so?

```
public void addBeginning(Integer val){
    node = new Node(val,null);
}

private void addLast(Node<Integer> node, Integer item){
if(node.next != null){
          addLast(node.next, item);
    }else{
          node.next = new Node<Integer>(item, null);
    }       
}

public void add(Integer val){
    if(node == null){
        addBeginning(val);
    }else{
        addLast(node,val);
    }
}
```

main class

```
//set is class name;
Set set = new Set();
set.add(25);        
set.add(26);
set.add(25);
set.add(25);
set.add(28);
```

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates or prevent duplicates from being added in the first place...?

Comment: i want to remove the duplicate elements. so if 25 is exists, then the next element 25 will be removed

Comment: Why are you using a linkedlist as the backing data structure here? Is that a requirement for the homework?

Comment: to be honest yea, it is the requirement. i suffered with this method for 2 hours

Comment: Keep a set of the input values.  only actually insert the value if it is not already in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent duplicates from getting into set create the following function:

```
boolean canAdd(Integer value) {
  Node current = this.node;
  while (current !=null) {
    if (current.value.equals(value)) {
      return false;
    }
    current = current.next;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Use this in your `add()` function to check if the value should be added or not.

In real-world application you can use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done efficiently if the items in the linked list are not ordered, because you would have to eliminate the duplications at every print of the list (or cache it).

The name of your linked list class (`Set`) assumes that you would like to implement a set. In this case the best solution is to not store the duplications at all, but order the unique items in the linked list at insertion (so you wouldn't have to check the whole linked list for a match at every push/pop operation).

Please note, that a set may be implemented in a more efficient way with using a (binary) search tree instead of a linked list.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter was probably right about the basic answer, but the observation that `Set` is a terrible name for a class that implements a LinkedList - or for that matter, pretty much any class since it duplicates `java.util.Set`.   So I'm upvoting for justice.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28java.util.Collection%29) as follows:

```
new java.util.HashSet(listCollection);
```

... and you'll have the collection without duplicate elements.